# Make a scatter plot from two columns of matrix

Tags: plotting

I have imported my text-type data as a matrix. I want to make a scatter plot (`ListPlot`) using one column as *x-axis* and other columns as *y-axis*.

Is there a function `F` which can make a scatter plot in the following form?

```
F[matrix[[All, 1]], {matrix[[All,2],...,matrix[[All,n]]]]
```

Answer (score 5):

E.g.:

```
test = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 6}, {3, 5, 9, 11}};

ListPlot[Map[Thread[List[#[[1]], #[[2 ;;]]]] &, test], PlotStyle -> PointSize[.02]]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear, I really cannot understand your method.Fist, my data is a matrix why still using List to form a list. Sceond, what does the function Thread and Map here. I have searched these functions in reference center. I could understand these functions respectively. But, when these functions combined, it really confused me.

Comment: @wikichung: Arrays are just specializations of lists (they *are* lists, in other words). The `Thread` piece is a short way of making a list of lists with some constant element, `Map` takes that over all of the data. Let me know if that's clear...

Comment: it works and can plot many lines

Comment: @wikichung: Glad to hear. Consider accepting an answer (little check-mark) that best fits your question.

Comment: it works and can plot many lines.ListPlot[Map[Thread[List[#[[1]], {#[[i]],#[[j]]}]] &, test], PlotStyle -> PointSize[.02]]

Comment: Thank you, dear. I still need to understand your method deeply, and know how to solve such question.:)

Answer (score 4):

The *new-in-9* `TemporalData` can be convenient for the current task:

```
data = RandomReal[10, {30, 5}];
td = TemporalData[Rest@Transpose@data, {First@Transpose@data}];
ListPlot[td, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your method, but it did not work. :(

Comment: @wikichung, what are the `Dimensions` of your `matrix` (what do you get when you evaluate `Dimensions[matrix]`?) Does the method work if you remove the `Transpose@` pieces in the code in this post?

Comment: my data are collected by a collector, so it is a 8000x9 matrix. The first column is the time, and others column is my signals.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

This approach correct if Length[xAxisdData]==Length[yAxesdData[[i]]]

```
xAxisdData={1,2,3,4};
yAxesdData={{1,2,3,4},{1,4,9,16}};
dataToPlot=Transpose[{xAxisdData,#}]&/@yAxesdData;
ListPlot[dataToPlot,PlotStyle->PointSize[.02]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your matrix looks like:

```
list = Table[5 i + j, {i, 10}, {j, 10}];
```

if so, you can convert the table into the matrixform with:

```
MatrixForm[list];
```

and plot every Line as usual:

```
ListPlot[{list[[1]], list[[2]], list[[8]]}]
```

[image: plot1]

If you like to plot Line 1 vs Line 6 you can use:

```
ListPlot[{list[[1]], list[[6]]} // Transpose]
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: Dear, my data are collected by a collector, so it is a 8000x9 matrix. The first column is the time, and others  column is my signals. It seems that my matrix does not fit your supposed form.

Comment: My data are collected by a collector, so it is a 8000x9 matrix. The first column is the time, and others column is my signals. it seems that my matrix does not fit your supposed form.

Answer (score 1):

For this, [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) (shorthand `[[]]`) is your friend. Using

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {20, 5}];
```

as the data set, you can extract multiple columns as follows:

```
data[[All, {x, y}]]
```

where `x` is the x-column and `y` is the y-column. Note, `x` can equal `y` and even be larger than `y`. Their values are only constrained by the number of columns, with one exception: negative indices are treated as starting from the end of the list, not the beginning like positive indices. To get multiple data sets, you have to be a little creative,

```
data[[All, {1, #}]]& /@ Range[2, Length@data[[1]]]
```