# Interpolating a plot with missing values

Tags: plotting, graphics, interpolation

With

```
data = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 5}, {8, 
   4}, {10, 3}, {10, 2}, {11, 1}}
```

and

```
ListLinePlot[data, Filling -> Axis, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

we get:

[image]

In reality, my datasets oftentimes have missing values. Setting f.e.

```
data[[3]] = {3, Missing[]}
```

I obtain with `Off[ListLinePlot::ioproc]` this picture,

[image]

nicely not-showing the missing point.

Unfortunately though, the smoothing vanished.

Could you propose a general way (plots may vary in size and may have multiple sets) to interpolate over missing values?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Based on the ideas presented here I have written this little function:

```
Smoother[v_] := If[smooth != 2, v, Select[#, #[[2]] != "na" &] & /@ v]
```

Turning `Smoother` on or off (via a button) I now get what I hoped for:

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you saying you *want* to keep the gap?  Try using `Split[]` and plot the parts separately.

Comment: Are the x values (`data[[All,1]]`) always sorted/non-decreasing as in your example?

Comment: @kguler: Yes, they are. Actually, I made a mistake in my question: The x-values should have gone from 1 to 11 (I forgot the 9 and doubled the 10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know how "general" you want it, but:

```
data = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 6},
   {7, 5}, {8, 4}, {10, 3}, {10, 2}, {11, 1}};
data1 = data;
data1[[3]] = {3, Missing[]};

GraphicsRow[ListLinePlot[#, Filling -> Axis, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 2] & /@ {data, Select[data1, #[[2]] =!= Missing[] &]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: nearly perfect, even better would be to leave the gap between 2 and 4 and smooth between 4 and 11. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the new-in-9 built-in [TemporalData](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TemporalData.html) which has the option `MissingDataMethod` to impute missing values.

```
dataOP = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, Missing[]}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 5},
          {8, 4}, {9, 3}, {10, 2}, {11, 1}};
states = dataOP[[All, 2]];
times = dataOP[[All, 1]];
style = {Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full, LabelStyle -> {"Panel", 14}, ImageSize -> 400};

tD = TemporalData[states, {times}, MissingDataMethod -> Automatic];
Row[Table[Quiet@ListLinePlot[dt, style, PlotStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[.03], Thick}],
                InterpolationOrder -> 2], {dt, {dataOP, tD}}],  Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Default setting for `InterpolationOrder` suboption seems to be `0`.

```
{td1, td2, td3} = TemporalData[states, {times},
        MissingDataMethod -> {"Interpolation",InterpolationOrder -> #}] & /@ {0, 1, 2};
Grid[i = 1; Table[Quiet@ListLinePlot[dt, style, InterpolationOrder -> io,
  PlotStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[.03], Thick, Opacity[.8],
                         ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[i++]]}],
  PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["InterpolationOrder-> `1`\nMissingDataMethod->`2`",
         io, MissingDataMethod /. dt[[2, -1]]], 14]] /. 
    Point[x : {__}] :> {Point[x], Red, PointSize[.04], Point[x[[3]]]},
{dt, {td1, td2}}, {io, {0, 1, 2}}], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

With modified data with more missing values, the effect of the suboption values become more visible:

```
dataA = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, Missing[]}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 7}, {7, Missing[]}, 
         {8, Missing[]}, {9, 3}, {10, 2}, {11, 3}, {12, 3}, {13, 3}, {14, 3}};
statesA = dataA[[All, 2]];
timesA = dataA[[All, 1]];
{td1A, td2A, td3A} =  TemporalData[statesA, {timesA}, 
      MissingDataMethod -> {"Interpolation",  InterpolationOrder -> #}] & /@ {0, 1, 3};

Grid[i = 1; Table[Quiet@ ListLinePlot[dt, style, InterpolationOrder -> io,
    PlotStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[.03], Thick, Opacity[.8], 
          ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[i++]]}], 
  PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["InterpolationOrder-> `1`\nMissingDataMethod->`2`",
         io, MissingDataMethod /. dt[[2, -1]]], 14]] /. 
    Point[x : {__}] :> {Point[x], Red, PointSize[.04], Point[x[[{3, 7, 8}]]]}, 
 {dt, {td2A, td3A}}, {io, {0, 1, 3}}], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: EXTREMELY interesting - I've never seen this "TemporalData" mentioned anywhere in SE or elsewhere before.

Comment: @eldo, there is this [recent Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48116/125) where i used  `TemporalData`, and few others that come up when I search this site.

Comment: The problem with TemporalData in my special case is that it fills out ALL consecutive missing points. To get a clear picture you really have to color them red like you did. With multiple sets I get a very colorfull, distracting image. On the other hand, I discovered countless other features of TemporalData which I can use in the future. So, many many thanks for your +1 presentation :)

Comment: @eldo, my pleasure.

Answer (score 4):

I gathered from some of the comments it might be desirable to retain
the gap in the figure:

```
 data = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 5},
           {8, 4}, {10, 3}, {10, 2}, {11, 1}}
 data[[3]] = {3, Missing[]}
 ListLinePlot[
     Select[ Split[data, Head[#1[[2]]] == Head[#2[[2]]] &] ,
          ( NumberQ[#[[1, 2]]]) &], 
 Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> GrayLevel[.5], 
     GridLines -> Automatic, Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full, 
     PlotMarkers -> Automatic, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
     PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

```
 ListLinePlot[
    s = Select[ 
        Split[data, 
        Head[#1[[2]]] == Head[#2[[2]]] &] , ( NumberQ[#[[1, 2]]]) &], 
        Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> GrayLevel[.5], 
        GridLines -> Automatic, Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full, 
        PlotMarkers -> Automatic, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
        PlotStyle -> Black, 
        Epilog -> {Dashed, 
           Line[{#[[1, -1]], #[[2, 1]]}] & /@ Partition[s, 2, 1]}]
```

[image]

ps. use eg.  `FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.25], Blue]` so the fill doesn't cover the grid.

Comment: using dashed lines is certainly a further improvement. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Fill in the missing values by interpolation. The following simple example does not handle all cases (e.g., consecutive missing values).

```
data = Sort[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, Missing[]},
    {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, Missing[]},
    {8, 4}, {10, 3}, {10, 2}, {11, 1}}];
(* Sort to make sure data is ordered prior to interpolation *)

(data[[#]] = {data[[#, 1]],
       Interpolation[
         {data[[# - 1]], data[[# + 1]]}][data[[#, 1]]]}) & /@ 
   Flatten[Position[data, {_, Missing[]}]]; // Quiet

Note that ListLinePlot does not need to use Joined option

ListLinePlot[data,
 Filling -> Axis,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 Mesh -> Full,
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

If the data does not include repeated x values (e.g., {..., {10, 3}, {10, 2}, ...}), delete missing data, interpolate, and use Plot.

```
data = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, Missing[]},
   {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, Missing[]},
   {8, 4}, {10, 3}, {11, 1}};

data = DeleteCases[data, {_, Missing[]}];

f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 2];

Plot[f[x],
 {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 Filling -> Axis,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[data]}
 ]
```

Bob Hanlon

Comment: Thanks, your first proposal works fine with my data and delivers the same image as belisarius' solution using "Select". When I use your Plot[f[x]... the image is somehow distorted.