# Simplify 2D polyhedral Regions like Interval

Tags: simplifying-expressions, regions, polyhedra

I don't think there's a built in "`RegionSimplify`" for polyhedral Regions and [derived](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DerivedRegions.html) akin to how Interval automatically simplifies its argument expression:

```
Interval[{0, 1}, {1, 2}]
```

and

```
Interval[{0, 1}]~IntervalUnion~Interval[{1, 2}]
```

yield

```
Interval[{0, 2}]
```

In contrast, `RegionUnion` remains unevaluated, even in 2D:

```
Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]~ RegionUnion ~ Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}]

(* RegionUnion[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}]] *)
```

From

```
Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}] ~ RegionUnion ~ 
  Rectangle[{1, 0}, {2, 1}] // RegionBoundary // DiscretizeRegion
```

[image]

As expected, the `Rectangles`' common segment is not part of the output.

How to expose or compute the ideal normal form for 2D (at least) polyhedral Regions like these basic examples:

Overlapping lines:

```
Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}]~ RegionUnion ~ Line[{{1, 0}, {3, 0}}] (* // RegionSimplify *)

(*  Line[{{0,0},{3,0}}] *)
```

Union of rectangles:

```
 Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}] ~ RegionUnion ~ 
      Rectangle[{1, 0}, {2, 1}] (* // RegionSimplify *)

(* Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}] *)
```

Boundary:

```
 Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}] ~ RegionUnion ~ 
      Rectangle[{1, 0}, {2, 1}] // RegionBoundary  (* // RegionSimplify *)

(* Line[{{0,0},{2,0},{2,1},{0,1},{0,0}}]  *)
```

The simplification should work for all 2D polyhedral regions including cones (which btw the current language does not support correctly):

```
ConicHullRegion[{{0, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 1}}] ~RegionUnion ~ 
 ConicHullRegion[{{0, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}}] (* // RegionSimplify *)

(* ConicHullRegion[{{0, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}] *)
```

For convex regions and convex-preserving operations (eg intersection) should suffice to consider the extreme set (vertices and rays), but in general regions aren't convex (and union doens't preserve it).

(Note: `RegionIntersection` of the same `Rectangles` hangs the kernel w/ msg: `Last::nolast: "{} has a length of zero and no last element"`)

Answer (score 1):

```
eps = 0.001;
repl = (z_Symbol == val_) :> 
   (val - eps/2 <= z <= val + eps/2);

r1 = Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}];
r2 = Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}];

r3 = ImplicitRegion[RegionMember[
     RegionUnion[r1, r2], {x, y}] //
    Simplify, {x, y}] /. repl

ImplicitRegion[(x | y) \[Element] Reals && -0.0005 <= y <= 0.0005 && 
  0 <= x <= 2, {x, y}]

r3 // DiscretizeRegion
```

[image]

```
r4 = Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}];
r5 = Line[{{1, 0}, {3, 0}}];

r6 = ImplicitRegion[RegionMember[
     RegionUnion[r4, r5], {x, y}] //
    Simplify, {x, y}] /. repl

ImplicitRegion[(x | y) \[Element] Reals && -0.0005 <= y <= 0.0005 && 
  0 <= x <= 3, {x, y}]

r6 // DiscretizeRegion
```

[image]

```
r7 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];
r8 = Rectangle[{1, 0}, {2, 1}];
r9 = RegionUnion[r7, r8];

RegionMember[r9, {x, y}] // Simplify

(x | y) \[Element] Reals && 0 <= x <= 2 && 0 <= y <= 1

r9 // DiscretizeRegion
```

[image]

```
r10 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];
r11 = Rectangle[{1, 0}, {2, 1}];
r12 = RegionUnion[r10, r11];

RegionMember[r12, {x, y}] // Simplify

(x | y) \[Element] Reals && 0 <= x <= 2 && 0 <= y <= 1

r12 // DiscretizeRegion
```

[image]

```
n = 5;
rectangles = 
  Rectangle @@@ 
   Transpose[{RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {n, 2}], 
     RandomInteger[{11, 20}, {n, 2}]}];

Graphics[{Opacity[.25], rectangles}]
```

[image]

```
r13 = RegionUnion @@ rectangles;

RegionMember[r13, {x, y}]

(x | y) \[Element] 
  Reals && ((2 <= x <= 13 && 3 <= y <= 14) || (2 <= x <= 14 && 
     4 <= y <= 11) || (3 <= x <= 16 && 
     8 <= y <= 19) || (4 <= x <= 13 && 
     9 <= y <= 13) || (5 <= x <= 17 && 8 <= y <= 13))

r13 // DiscretizeRegion
```

[image]

EDIT: Example of disconnected regions

```
r14 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];
r15 = Rectangle[{1.1, 1.1}, {1.6, 1.7}];
r16 = RegionUnion[r14, r15];

RegionMember[r16, {x, y}] // Simplify

(x | y) \[Element] 
  Reals && ((0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1) || (1.1 <= x <= 1.6 && 
     1.1 <= y <= 1.7))

r16 // DiscretizeRegion
```

[image]

SECOND EDIT: Additional example--regions with holes.

```
r1 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];
r2 = Rectangle[{.25, .25}, {.5, .5}];
r3 = RegionDifference[r1, r2];
r4 = Disk[{1.5, 1.25}, .75];
r5 = Rectangle[{1.25, 1.25}, {1.75, 1.35}];
r6 = RegionDifference[r4, r5];
r7 = RegionUnion[r3, r6];

RegionMember[r7, {x, y}]
```

> (x | y) [Element]    Reals && (((-1.5 + x)^2 + (-1.25 + y)^2 <= 
>         0.5625 && ! (1.25 <= x <= 1.75 && 1.25 <= y <= 1.35)) || (0 <= 
>         x <= 1 && 
>        0 <= y <= 1 && ! (0.25 <= x <= 0.5 && 0.25 <= y <= 0.5)))

```
DiscretizeRegion[r7]
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `Union` of `Rectangles` that isn't simply-connected?

Comment: Added example of disconnected regions.

Comment: Those components are simply connected. Try something w/ a hole in it.

Comment: Added example with regions with holes. If this is not what you want, provide a specific example of what you do want.

Comment: Your method using `RegionMember` and `Simplify`, unlike Junho's, seems robust to the more complex topologies but it doesn't yield the normal form, which is the minimal number of boundary points (for polytopes).

Comment: Btw, `Disc` is not a polyhedron.

Answer (score 0):

(version 10) I made function `lastUnion` , `firstUnion` and `RectangleRegionSimplify` instead of `RegionSimplify`. I think you might want to make `RectangleRegionSimplify`.

```
lastUnion[coo_] := 
 Flatten[Replace[SplitBy [ coo, Last], {f_, ___, l_} -> {f, l}, 1], 1]
firstUnion[coo_] := 
 Flatten[Replace[SplitBy [ coo, First], {f_, ___, l_} -> {f, l}, 1], 1]
RectangleRegionSimplify[p__] := Module[{pts, rst},
  pts = MeshPrimitives[
     BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
      DiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion@p], MaxCellMeasure -> \[Infinity]],
      2][[1, 1]];
  rst = Append[pts, First[pts]];
  rst = N[Rationalize[Chop[rst, 10^-6]], 5];
  rst // firstUnion // lastUnion // Rationalize // N // Line
]
```

And I made some sample `Rectangle`'s as `Region`. `Rectangle` is not always `Region`, so I randomly selected those as `Region`.

```
n = 5;
data = Transpose[{RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {n, 2}], 
    RandomInteger[{11, 20}, {n, 2}]}];
fig1 = {ColorData["Atoms", "ColorList"][[1 ;; n]], 
    Rectangle @@@ data} // Transpose;
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], Opacity[0.3], fig1}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

I think you can check for your code with following like this.

```
fig2 = RectangleRegionSimplify[RegionUnion @@ Rectangle @@@ data]
```

> `Line[{{4., 8.}, {5., 8.}, {5., 5.}, {7., 5.}, {7., 1.}, {12., 
>      1.}, {12., 3.}, {16., 3.}, {16., 5.}, {19., 5.}, {19., 14.}, {15., 
>      14.}, {15., 19.}, {4., 19.}, {4., 8.}}]`

```
Graphics[{%, PointSize[Large], Red, Point @@ %}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

**Caution**

```
RegionQ[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 3}]]
```

> `True`

```
RegionQ[Rectangle[{2, 0}, {1, 3}]]
```

> `False`

Comment: Junho, it doesn't work on *derived* `Regions`, eg: `Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}]~RegionUnion~ Rectangle[{1, 0}, {2, 2}]`. Derived implies `RegionQ[r]==True`

Comment: Applying `Normal` to `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` is still a graphic. How to extract the line representation? Also note: `...// BoundaryDiscretizeRegion // RegionBoundary` outputs many points that are not corners.

Comment: as per the calendar counterexample, try rectangles whose union is not simply connected. Also, the method should work for all 2D polyhedra and derived regions.

Comment: Your method fails if the union is not simply-connected, eg this "#" shape: `data2 = {{{1, 0}, {2, 6}}, {{4, 0}, {5, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {6, 2}}, {{4, 0}, {5, 6}}, {{0, 4}, {6, 5}}}` with msg: `There is no simple cell representation for the specified cells of the BoundaryMeshRegion...`