# Drawing two graphics with an arrow in between

Tags: graphics, drawing

I'm trying to draw two graphics object well defined and an arrow in between pointing left to right (symbolizing the mapping between the two). I've tried drawing the arrow first in a graphics object and then using `GraphicsRow` but the end result is unsatisfying: I get that the arrow takes a third of the space, when I would like it much smaller. How could I get there?

Comment: Select the graphics, Right-click, "Drawing Tools"

Comment: @belisarius: I did it this way in the past, but I would be interested in a systematic way of doing it.

Comment: Then check out [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14149/193). It's a nice mix of both, I believe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gF = Graphics[{#[[1]], #[[2]], Black, 
     Text[Style["\[RightArrow]", 72, Bold], Scaled@{.5, 1/2}],
     #2[[1]], Translate[#2[[2]], {3., 0}]}, ImageSize -> 500] &;

gF[{Blue, Disk[]}, {Red, Polygon[{{1, -1}, {0, Sqrt[3] - 1}, {-1, -1}}]}]
```

[image]

```
gF[{Blue, Polygon[Table[{Cos[2 \[Pi] k/6], Sin[2 \[Pi] k/6]}, {k, 0,  5}]]},
   {Red,  Polygon[Table[{Cos[2 \[Pi] k/9], Sin[2 \[Pi] k/9]}, {k, 0, 8}]]}]
```

[image]

Or

```
g1 = Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, BaselinePosition -> Center, ImageSize -> 300];
g2 = Graphics[{Red, Polygon[{{4, -1}, {3, Sqrt[3] - 1}, {2, -1}}]}, 
   BaselinePosition -> Center, ImageSize -> 300];
g3 = Graphics[{Orange, Polygon[Table[{Cos[2 \[Pi] k/9], Sin[2 \[Pi] k/9]}, {k, 0, 8}]]}, 
   BaselinePosition -> Center, ImageSize -> 300];
g4 = Graphics[Text@Style["\[RightArrow]", 64, Bold], BaselinePosition -> Center, ImageSize -> 50];

Row[{g1, g2, g3}, g4]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you, it works like a charm indeed!

Comment: @Learningisamess, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 Manipulate[Show[{
   Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}],
   Graphics[{Red, Polygon[{{4, -1}, {3, Sqrt[3] - 1}, {2, -1}}]}],
   Graphics[{Darker@Green, Thickness[0.007], 
     Arrow[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y1}}]}]

   }], {{x1, 1}, 0, 3}, {{y1, 0.1}, 0, 3}, {{x2, 2.5}, 0, 3}]
```

and play with the sliders. You should see the following:

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

In practice, the output form of `Rule` is effective for combinations of graphics and other expressions. For example, see:

- My answer to [Temporal database reconstruction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60927/temporal-database-reconstruction-in-mathematica/61812#61812) (note existing rules in `Association` and `Dataset`)
- Try kguler's graphics with `g1 -> g2 -> g3`
- Can be used to quikly make legends for figures from `Associations`. Given `data = <| "a" -> Red, "b" -> Blue|>`, `data // Normal // Column // Panel` gives:

[image]

Limitations include:

- The result is not a `Graphics` object (though often it renders to PDF just fine).
- No control over the arrow's style (or is there?)